# How are you using CFThread in ColdFusion Applications?

Tags: concurrency, coldfusion

I'm presenting on Concurrency in ColdFusion at `CFObjective` this year, and I'd like to hear how you're using `CFThread` in your ColdFusion applications.

In addition, what problems have you had while using it, and how (if at all) have you solved them?

What do you dislike about `CFThread`?

Have you run into significant weaknesses with `CFThread` or other problems where it simply could not do what you wanted to do?

Finally, if there's anything you'd like to add related to concurrency in CF, not specifically related to `CFThread`, please do tell.

Thanks!

Comment: I'll see you give your presentation. I'll be taking notes. :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Asked here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/143226/how-are-you-using-cfthread-in-coldfusion-applications

Answer (score 1):

We have a pdf generation system that needs to popluate thousands of PDF forms, merge them and send them to a print system.

I use a seperate thread to populate the pdf forms.  When all the threads are done I merge the results into seperate batches of document packages.

This way I can be creating multiple PDFS rather than in a sequential order.

Tim Cunningham

Comment: Tim, is this your typical thread.run() thread.join() kind of thing? Have you encountered any problems with it?